# 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not callable

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to connect Python with SQLite and make a GUI for it. So here is some of the code below:

```
db_name = 'database.db'
def run_query(self, query, parameters =()):
    with sqlite3.connect (self.db_name) as conn:
         cursor = conn.cursor()
         query_result = cursor.execute (query, parameters)
         conn.commit()
    return query_result()




def viewing_records (self):
    records = self.tree.get_children()
    for element in records:
        self.tree.delete (element)
    query = 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY name DESC'
    db_rows = self.run_query (query)
    for row in db_rows:
        self.tree.insert('', 0, text = row[1], values = row[2])
```

The probleme is when I run self.viewing_records () I get the following error 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not callable. Can someone help, please?

Comment: Why is `conn.commit()` required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return query_result()` tries to use a call (`()`) on the cursor object. Just return the cursor *without calling*:

```
return query_result
```